# What does setFilterMap on android do?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I was working on a livewallpaper for Android. Drawing the Bitmap on the screen made the edges look very jagged, even though the source of the bitmap was of high quality. After some searches on the internet and some random experiments, I found that using `paint.setFilterMap(true)` rendered the bitmap without any jagged edges(although it did hit performance pretty badly).

I found this explanation in the documentation: "Filtering affects the sampling of bitmaps when they are transformed."

Can anyone explain what that means? Also any other suggestions for drawing smooth bitmaps are welcome.